# How to draw a 9x9 grid in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw a 9x9 grid in python using turtle graphics. I know that I need to use two for loops, one for the vertical lines and one for the horizontal lines. However, the only thing that I can get is a large square on the screen. When I try to draw the lines, I get an error. This is my program so far:

```
def main():

    import turtle
    x=turtle.Turtle()
    x.penup()
    x.goto(-300,300)
    x.pendown()
    for i in range(4):
        x.forward(600)
        x.right(90)

main()
```

Can someone help me draw the grid?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "i need two for loops" but you only have one. also, giving you a big square is exactly what it's supposed to do with the code you quoted. do you try to make us do your homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import turtle


def main():
    x = turtle.Turtle()
    x.penup()
    x.goto(-150, -150)
    x.pendown()
    x.left(90)
    for i in xrange(2):
        for j in xrange(4):
            x.right(90)
            x.pendown()
            x.forward(300)
            x.right(180)
            x.forward(300)
            x.right(90)
            x.penup()
            x.forward(100)
        x.backward(100)
        x.right(90)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of using turtle to draw N x N grids comes up often and solutions are usually size-specific, or inefficient.  Let's address both with a simple grid drawing routine that handles N x N grids:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

N = 9  # N by N grid
LENGTH = 30  # each grid element will be LENGTH x LENGTH pixels

def grid(turtle, n, length):
    sign = 1
    for _ in range(2):

        for _ in range(n):
            turtle.forward(length * n)
            turtle.left(sign * 90)
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.left(sign * 90)
            sign = 0 - sign

        turtle.forward(length * n)
        [turtle.right, turtle.left][n % 2](90)
        sign = 0 - sign

screen = Screen()
yertle = Turtle()

yertle.penup()
yertle.goto(-N * LENGTH/2, -N * LENGTH/2)  # center our grid (optional)
yertle.pendown()

grid(yertle, N, LENGTH)

screen.exitonclick()
```

The algorithm serpentines the horizontal lines:

[image]

and then turns 90 degrees and does the same for the vertical lines:

[image]

There is some redrawing of line segments but it's kept to a minimum.  Although some algorithms posted to solve this sort of problem loop N * N times, this one only loops 2 * N to draw the grid.

[image]